# Unit test code on Azure.Data.Tables methods

Tags: azure, unit-testing, mocking, azure-table-storage

getting below error while writing unit test cases for azure table storage functions.

Mock does not contain a definition for 'GetTableClient' and no accessible extension method 'GetTableClient' accepting a first argument ...

I'm trying to do unit test of table storage functions,
below is the sample i'm trying,

```
        var tableServiceClient = new Mock<TableServiceClient >("AzureWebJobsStorage");
        var tableClient = tableServiceClient.GetTableClient("Dummytable");
        
        var mockResponse = new Mock<Response>();
        mockResponse.SetupGet(x => x.Status).Returns((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        mockResponse.SetupGet(x => x.Content).Returns(BinaryData.FromString("data source here"));

        tableClient.Setup(x => x.DeleteEntityAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), default, default)).ReturnsAsync(mockResponse.Object);
   
        var response = tableClient.DeleteEntityAsync(itemrow,itemrow);
```

Assert(response, mockresponse)

but i'm getting errors.